# Why do my url rewriting rules throw me a 500 Internal Server Error on my localhost?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Note: I have uncommented the line for loading `rewrite_module`

I have the following `.htaccess`:

```
SetEnv PHP_VER 5_4
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^lang/(.+)/(.+)$  index.php?mod=lang&lang=$1&url=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.+)/(.+)/(.+)/(.+).html$  index.php?mod=$1&var=$2&svar=$3&tvar=$4 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.+)/(.+)/(.+).html$  index.php?mod=$1&var=$2&svar=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.+)/(.+).html$  index.php?mod=$1&var=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.+).html$  index.php?mod=$1 [L]
```

It works fine on my remote server but in local I get a 500 Internal Server Error. I am using UwAmp (portable version of Wamp Server) with PHP 5.4. I used to work on my old computer but not on my new one (both on Windows 7) what can I do ?

Comment: what does the error log say?

Comment: [Sun Aug 16 17:38:45.869419 2015] [core:alert] [pid 4332:tid 1148] [client 127.0.0.1:59705] C:/UwAmp/www/pricing/.htaccess: Either all Options must start with + or -, or no Option may., referer: http://127.0.0.1/

Comment: Do you have the appropriate `AllowOverride` directive in your server config to permit the use of mod_rewrite in .htaccess? Since you are using a relative path substitution, you should really have a `RewriteBase` directive (although not the cause of this problem).

Comment: What happens when you comment out `Options` line?